# What is type <U12?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, types

I was using `pandas` and `numpy` to process some data until I got two similar output of arrays:

```
array(['french', 'mexican', 'cajun_creole', ..., 'southern_us', 'italian',
       'thai'], dtype='<U12')

array(['french', 'mexican', 'cajun_creole', ..., 'jamaican', 'italian',
   'thai'], dtype=object)
```

I don't see the difference, what is `<U12`?

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question: it's all [in the manual: `arrays.dtypes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`<U12` That is a numpy type:

`<` Little Endian

`U` Unicode

`12` 12 characters:

([Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types))

Comment: Prize for maximum usefulness to brevity ratio.

Comment: @piRSquared, been practicing my brevity.  Characters are expensive.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in how elements are stored.

`<U12` stores them flat, zero-padding each entry to length 12. To see this we can use `tobytes` to directly access the data buffer:

```
>>> au
array(['french', 'mexican', 'cajun_creole', 'Ellipsis', 'southern_us',
       'italian', 'thai'], dtype='<U12')
>>> 
>>> sz = au.dtype.itemsize
>>> [au.tobytes()[i:i+sz].decode('utf32') for i in range(0, au.size * sz, sz)]
['french\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'mexican\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'cajun_creole', 'Ellipsis\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'southern_us\x00', 'italian\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'thai\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

`object` stores only object references, i.e. pointers to `str` objects. We can verify this using the fact that---in the current CPython implementation---`id` returns a Python object's memory address:

```
>>> ao
array(['french', 'mexican', 'cajun_creole', Ellipsis, 'southern_us',
       'italian', 'thai'], dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> sz = ao.dtype.itemsize
>>> [int.from_bytes(ao.tobytes()[i:i+sz], 'little') for i in range(0, ao.size * sz, sz)]
[140626141129896, 140625895652128, 140625895628080, 8856512, 140625895627504, 140626141132200, 140626343518024]
>>> [id(it) for it in ao]
[140626141129896, 140625895652128, 140625895628080, 8856512, 140625895627504, 140626141132200, 140626343518024]
```

Answer (score 0):

### #Correct Python code is below

```py
import numpy as np

#declating list of values
l2=['french', 'Mexican', 'cajun_creole', ..., 'southern_us', 'Italian',
       'Thai'] 

arr2=np.array(l2) #assigning the list of values to the array by alias name
print(l2)# printing the list
print(arr2)# printing the array
print(type(arr2))#represents the type of array
print(arr2.ndim) #count of the number of square brackets at beginning/end of the array
print(arr2.shape)# shape represented
print(arr2.size)# number of list declared in array
print(arr2.dtype) # represents the Uni code format of strings declared in the List
```

[image: result]